# Using MySQL Connector/C++ v2.0 with CMake?

Tags: c++, mysql-connector, build-error

I'm trying to use [*MySQL Connector/C++ v2*](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp) in my application, I'm using CLion as IDE, so I build using CMake, but I can't manage to make CMake understand that I need it.

I included *MySQL Connector/C++* like this:

```
# Build external libs
add_subdirectory(external/mysql-connector-cpp)
```

and I simply added:

```
# Add libs
target_link_libraries(libconcpp)
```

My CMake environnement is reloading greatly, but I get a linking error as the lib was not included..
I also add includes with the correct directive in CMakeLists.txt.

Thanks !

Comment: `target_link_libraries(libconcpp)` you missed specifying the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your target_link_libraries() you missed specifying the target:

```
target_link_libraries(libconcpp)
```

It should be:

```
target_link_libraries(myTargetName libconcpp)
```

where `myTargetName` is the name of your target you specified in `add_excecutable()` or `add_library()`.